# NextRouter was not mounted. NextJS

Tags: css, next.js13

I want to make it active when it is on the home page by changing its color

i use Next Router and it show error

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

my code

```
import Link from "next/link";
import "./navbar.css";
import routes from "@/routes/routes";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Navbar() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <header className="navbar">
     
        <nav className="navbar-wrap">
          <Link href={routes.home} className="navbar-logo">
            <span className="logo">KhuongVietTai</span>
          </Link>
          <div className="navbar-panel">
            <ul className="panel-list">
              <li
                className={`panel-list-item ${
                  router.pathname === routes.home ? "active" : ""
                }`}
              >
                <Link className="panel-item-link" href={routes.home}>
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
```

css

```
.panel-list-item:hover .panel-item-link {
  color: var(--light-green);
}

.panel-list-item:active .panel-item-link {
  color: var(--light-green);
}
```

What I want is like this picture

[image]

When you are on the home page, the color will be different and there will be an underline. When you switch to another page, the next page will change color and have an underline below.

image 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using pathname here is one quick example of my code

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const pathname = usePathname();

{sidebarLinks.map((link) => {
      const isActive =
        (pathname.includes(link.route) && link.route.length > 1) ||
        pathname === link.route;
      return (
        <Link
          href={link.route}
          key={link.label}
          className={`leftsidebar_link ${isActive && "bg-primary-500"}`}
          suppressHydrationWarning
        >
          <Image src={link.imgURL} alt={link.alt} height={24} width={24} />
          <p className="text-light-1 max-lg:hidden">{link.label}</p>
        </Link>
      );
    })}
```

here is the array of sidebar links

```
export const sidebarLinks = [
 {
    imgURL: "/assets/home.svg",
    route: "/",
    label: "Home",
    alt: "Home icon"
 },
 {
    imgURL: "/assets/search.svg",
    route: "/search",
    label: "Search",
    alt: "Search icon"
 },
 {
    imgURL: "/assets/heart.svg",
    route: "/activity",
    label: "Activity",
    alt: "Activity icon"
 },
]
```